# Spring 3 RadioButtonsTag Attribute 'items' must be an array, a Collection or a Map Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am populate a List of String as radio button in the JSP. I add the List to the ModelMap but still the below Exception occurred. What am i missing please?

> Attribute 'items' must be an array, a Collection or a Map:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute 'items' must be an
>   array, a Collection or a Map

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeManager employeeManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homePage(ModelMap map) {
        map.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
        populateDepartments(map);
        return "addEmployee";
    }

    private void populateDepartments(ModelMap map){
        List<String> departments = new ArrayList<String>();
        departments.add("Dept 1");
        departments.add("Dept 2");
        map.addAttribute("departments",departments);
    }
}
```

addEmployee.jsp:

```
<form:form method="post" action="add" commandName="employee">

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td><form:input path="address" /></td>
        <td>Departments</td>
        <td><form:radiobuttons path="empDepartment" items="${departments}"/></td> 
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
 </form:form>
```

The entity

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    @Transient
    private String empDepartment;
}
```

Comment: uhmmmm... all seems to be ok... have you tried (to test) with a `String[]` ?

Comment: Just for laughs, can you change `ModelMap` to `Model` and see if any changes? Also see this example :http://kruders.com/spring-mvc/spring-radiobutton-tag/ - it is done slightly differently.